# How to Return values for each iteration?i'm able to send only last iteration values to my db

Tags: java, loops, return, conditional-statements

I'm using deserialize method which return values at last.I'm using for loop.  first loop for getting each object and applying my stuff to each single object in second for loop.

My problem:

if I'm having 5 objects in the first loop all the 5 objects return values should be inserted in the database at the end of my program but only last (5th) object values are inserted into my database.ie.,only 5th object values are return at the end.(i declared all my obj in class not in the loop)

How can i store all 5 objects return values into my database.

How can I send each return values to db for each iteration.

```
public class MainParserSpout implements Scheme{

public List<Object> deserialize(byte[] arg0) {

    try{
        for(;;){
            //loop of objects
            for(;;){

                //mystuff for each object
                  }
              }

    }catch(Exception e){}

    return new Values(); 

}

public Fields getOutputFields() {
    return new Fields();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



}
```

Comment: store all those values in a list, and return the list. Once you triggered a return, the iteration is finished

Comment: You have *removed too much* code rendering the code pretty much useless, because I have no idea what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this; add each Object to the list and then return the list:

```
public List<Values> deserialize (byte[] arg0) {
    List<Values> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (some condition ...) { //while the byte array still has data or something
        Values v = new Values()
        //do soething with the Values object.
        list.add(v);
    }

    return list; //return the list with all the Values Objects.

}
```

If you want some more specific recommendation, you should make it clearer what you are trying to do, but this is probably the general idea you are looking for.